# Angular Kendo Grid: Background Color of Selected Row

Tags: css, angular, kendo-ui, telerik, angular11

How do I change the background color of Kendo Angular Grid row that is Selected? The following is not making the background color blue. Trying to figure out what is overriding it.

```
.k-grid .k-state-selected  {
  background-color: blue !important;
  color: green;
}
 
.k-grid .k-alt.k-state-selected {
  background-color: blue !important;
  color: green;
}
```

[image]

**Resources:**
https://www.telerik.com/forums/changing-color-of-selected-row

Comment: host ng deep is not working either

Comment: ng-deep should make this work.. if not can u check if [selectable]="true" is added in the <kendo-grid>

Comment: You either have to disable view-encapsulation or declare those overrides in the global styles.css file to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your styling doesn't affect the grid due to view encapsulation. You can read more about it [here](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation).

To force the use of your custom styling into a child component that has view encapsulation, which is set to `Emulated` by default for all components, add `::ng-deep` before the CSS selector, like this:

```
:host ::ng-deep .k-grid .k-state-selected  {
    background-color: blue !important;
    color: green;
}
  
:host ::ng-deep .k-grid .k-alt.k-state-selected {
    background-color: blue !important;
    color: green;
}
```

Since `::ng-deep` convert the styling into a global rule, you need to add `:host` before it so that it will affect only the current component and its children.

Note that `::ng-deep` is deprecated and technically shouldn't be used. A replacement is planned and `::ng-deep` will probably be around until they come up with something else.

You can read more about `::ng-deep` [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep).

Comment: forgot to mention host ng deep is not working either for me

Comment: Is the grid a direct child of the component where you placed the styling?